# Heroku: Storing local MongoDB to MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, deployment, heroku, mlab

It might be a dead simple question yet I still wanted to ask. I've created a Node.js application and deployed it on **Heroku**. I've also set up the database connection without having any trouble as well.

However, I cannot get the load the local data in my MongoDB to **MongoLab** I use on heroku. I've searched google and could not find a useful solution so I ended up trying these commands;

```
mongodump
```

And:

```
mongorestore -h mydburl:mydbport -d mydbname -u myusername -p mypassword --db Collect.1
```

Now when I run the command mongorestore, I received the error;

```
ERROR: multiple occurrences

Import BSON files into MongoDB.
```

When I take a look at the DB file for MongoDB I've specified and used during the local development, I see that there are files **Collect.0**, **Collect.1** and **Collect.ns**. Now I know that my db name is 'Collect' since when I use the shell I always type `use Collect`. So I specified the db as Collect.1 in command line but I still receive the same errors. Should I remove all the other collect files or there is another way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use 'mongorestore' against the raw database files. 'mongorestore' is meant to work off of a dump file generated by 'mongodump'. First us 'mongodump' to dump your local database and then use 'mongorestore' to restore that dump file.

If you go to the Tools tab in the MongoLab UI for your database, and click 'Import / Export' you can see an example of each command with the correct params for your database.

Email us at support@mongolab.com if you continue to have trouble.

-will

Answer (score 3):

This can done by two steps.

1.Dump the database

```
mongodump -d mylocal_db_name -o dump/
```

2.Restore the database

```
mongorestore -h xyz.mongolab.com:12345 -d remote_db_name -u username -p password dump/mylocal_db_name/
```